# Change selector assigned to tint programmatically

Tags: android, android-drawable

I've set a drawable to the tint of my ImageButton so the color of the icon changes automatically when the button is enabled or disabled, is there any way to change the tint programmatically after that so I keep the same behavior just with different colors for the enabled and disabled state?

**The content of my_layout.xml:**

```xml
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_minus"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@color/default_button_background"
    android:tint="@drawable/button_tint_color"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_remove_24px" />
```

**The content of button_tint_color.xml:**

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="@color/icon_tint_disable_color" />

    <item
        android:color="@color/icon_tint_enable_color" />
</selector>
```

Then in my code I can just do `buttonMinus.setEnabled(true)` or `buttonMinus.setEnabled(false)` and the icon color change automatically. Is there a way to set programmatically a different color for one or both the enabled color or disabled color ?

Comment: you need to create (or get from the button and edit) `StateListDrawable` programmatically

Comment: Is there no way to change the assigned drawable or apply a different theme with different values for the "icon_tint_disable_color" and "icon_tint_enable_color" constants ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way I found so far is to make a new color state list programmatically and assign it to the button, yikes, the goal was to avoid setting visual attributes like colors programmatically ...

```java
        ColorStateList buttonStates = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][] {
                        { -android.R.attr.state_enabled },
                        {}
                },
                new int[] {
                        Color.RED,
                        Color.BLUE
                }
        );

        buttonMinus.setImageTintList(buttonStates);
```

Comment: Why minus sign at android.R.attr.state_enabled?

Comment: @AtulGupta That's how you get the disabled state

Comment: Strange in my case it worked without - sign.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this I think:

```
if(buttonMinus.isEnabled()){
//With button enabled
yourIcon.setItemIconTintList(ColorStateList.ValueOf(yourColor));
}else{...}
```

Comment: No, the goal is to avoid to set the button visual attributes programmatically to avoid noise and bugs in the code.